Runtime Error: GPIO Pin Numbering Mode Not Set in Flask-Controlled Raspberry Pi Application
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time

# GPIO pin configuration
in1 = 23
in2 = 24
en1 = 12
in3 = 5
in4 = 6
en2 = 13

# HC-SR04 Pins
TRIG_PIN = 27
ECHO_PIN = 22

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Set the GPIO pin numbering mode
GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en2, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(TRIG_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO_PIN, GPIO.IN)

app = Flask(__name__)

def measure_distance():
    # Trigger the ultrasonic sensor
    GPIO.output(TRIG_PIN, False)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_PIN, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_PIN, False)

    # Measure the time it takes for the echo to return
    pulse_start = time.time()
    timeout_start = time.time()

    # Start the pulse
    while GPIO.input(ECHO_PIN) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time()
        if pulse_start - timeout_start > 0.1:  # 0.1 second timeout
            return float('inf')  # Return an infinite distance if no echo is received

    # End the pulse
    pulse_end = time.time()
    timeout_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_PIN) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()
        if pulse_end - timeout_start > 0.1:  # 0.1 second timeout
            return float('inf')  # Return an infinite distance if no echo is received

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
    distance = pulse_duration * 17150  # Distance in cm
    return round(distance, 2)

def move_forward():
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)

def stop():
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/forward')
def forward():
    distance = measure_distance()
    if distance >= 20:  # Adjust the threshold as needed
        move_forward()  # Keep moving forward if no obstacle detected
        return "Moving forward"
    else:
        stop()  # Stop if an obstacle is detected
        return f"Obstacle detected! Stopping. Distance = {distance:.2f} cm"

@app.route('/stop')
def stop_route():
    stop()
    return "Stopping"

@app.teardown_appcontext
def cleanup(exception=None):
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down the server...")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()

THe error:
192.168.43.1 - - [20/Oct/2024 14:42:47] "GET /stop HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mavemen/my_flask_app/ap2.py", line 79, in stop_route
    stop()
  File "/home/mavemen/my_flask_app/ap2.py", line 56, in stop
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

This is a Raspberry Pi-based mobile device project controlled via a Flask web interface. I'm trying to control the device using buttons on the web interface. When the forward button is pressed, the device moves forward, and it stops when the button is released. While the button is pressed, the device also uses the HC-SR04 sensor to detect obstacles. But an error occurs when I press the forward & stop button, and I'm unsure where the problem lies

What happens if you comment out the calls to cleanup?

@joan Idk how to do that ;-)

Replace the "GPIO.cleanup()" lines with "pass # GPIO.cleanup()".  That will add an empty statement.
